# C# linux mono runtime version supported by this application is unavailable

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, xbuild

i have seen other question on stackoverflow about thi topic but for me is different

this is my scenario (on ubuntu)

```
 airone@airone:~/LibUsbDotNet_Bin.2.2.8$ sudo mono Test_Info.exe 
 WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
 Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
 The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
 It should have been installed in the `/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll' directory.
 airone@airone:~/LibUsbDotNet_Bin.2.2.8$
```

in mono directory i get this

```
airone@airone:/usr/lib/mono$ ls -l
totale 148
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 dic  7 13:44 2.0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 20480 dic 13 01:24 2.0-api
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 dic 13 01:24 3.5-api
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 dic 13 01:24 4.0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 20480 dic 13 01:24 4.0-api
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 20480 dic 13 01:27 4.5
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 24576 dic 13 01:24 4.5-api
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 dic  7 13:44 aot-cache
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 dic  7 13:42 compat-2.0
drwxr-xr-x 234 root root 12288 dic  7 13:49 gac
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 dic 13 01:24 lldb
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 dic  7 13:44 mono-configuration-crypto
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 dic 13 01:27 monodoc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 dic  7 13:42 xbuild
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 dic  7 13:42 xbuild-frameworks
airone@airone:/usr/lib/mono$
```

in 4.5 there is thath file

```
airone@airone:/usr/lib/mono/4.5$ ls -l | grep msco
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1525760 dic 13 01:46 mscorlib.dll
airone@airone:/usr/lib/mono/4.5$
```

that drives me crazy

who help me ? thanks